# Java and Android mesh/star networking

Tags: android, networking, bluetooth, mesh-network

I'm currently working on an Android project that will need connecting to a Bluetooth device that will dispatch messages to different nodes. This means that I will have to pass the right messages to the appropriate nodes (many micro-controllers).

At the moment, I can send a string or receive a string from the master micro-controller and I think the best way to solve my problem will be that the master micro-controller node simply repeats and broadcasts the message to all the others nodes. For the Android part, I was wondering if it was a good practice to make an array that will contain the id of the receiver and after the data I want to send. The ID will be on 8 bits and the data will be a string. After I will cast the int to a string and concatenate both strings to send my id+data.

Is this a good way to solve my problem or there is a more elegant way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more efficient to cast the string to bytes and send it all as an array of bytes.  Serious network protocols would never use text data like that.  If you're just doing a for-fun trial that's ok though.

Here's the real problem I see with your mesh-  infinite exponential propagation.  Lets say I send a message to someone, and do it by sending it to all of my neighbors.  They'll forward it to all their neighbors.  Who'll forward it to all their neighbors.  Which if there's ever any loop in the graph will cause it to get sent back to someone who's already seen it, who will forward it again.  And it will never die.  Unless you have no loops, in which case you don't have a mesh and you're very fragile and will likely fragment.  You need some way of preventing retransit of the same message-  possibly as simple as a message id field and not retransmiting the same message id again.  You'd need a large pool of message numbers for that though-  something like a 128 bit UUID.

Comment: Actually, it is quite common today transmit numeric data over the network in its string representation - unless you are moving large volumes of data, the readability in logs and terminal-like debug clients, freedom from worrying about binary format issues such as endianness, etc, is often preferred despite the increase in data size, especially when the size isn't likely to be all that much greater than the overhead anyway.  You'll run into string representation all over the place in web services, SQL database interfaces, etc.

Comment: For the data layer, sometimes.  For the transport layer and routing layer?  Never.  It would be ok for a trial of how things work, but it would be hideous to scale for a serious implementation.  And it would be annoying to work in hardware, which if it was a serious attempt at a transport/routing layer protocol it would eventually need to be implemented in

Comment: In this case, the transport/routing layer you speak of will actually be implemented in-band in the data, and will be a pretty small amount of information.  Keeping it readable will be a major benefit at low cost.  And no, putting it into embedded hardware does not challenge that.  For example, on an embedded system's serial port, unless you are at the limit of the highest usable baudrate, it makes a lot more sense to make the system talk/accept ASCII rather than binary, since it is drastically easier to debug and develop clients for.  And you can use newlines to solve the framing problem.

Comment: I hugely disagree (although this seems like a learning project, so I'm speaking in general, not to this case).  I also don't think having an address in ascii is more readable than knowing the first X bytes are a hex address.  But its past midnight where I live so I'm not going to get into a coding philosophy battle.

Comment: You are welcome to disagree, but it is common practice in the industry to do it this way.  It's nearly worth it just to solve the framing problem on a link which doesn't necessarily give you packetization - contemplating ways to handle that with serial data emitted by an FPGA, I realized that outputting newline-terminated hex values in ASCII was both one of the simplest solutions to the framing problem to implement in Verilog (which is a downright spartan environment compared to embedded MCUs), and incidentally also the most human friendly.

Comment: There's not a single major networking protocol at that level that uses ASCII.  Not one.  Nor is it easier to read-  since the IDs aren't text (they're numbers) its actually easier to read as hex than as text.

Comment: Thank you for all your inputs. Because I may bridge bluetooth and  2.5GHz RF in my project I think I will need to send bytes but this is good to know that using ASCII is used in the industry and I may do that for further project that will have only Bluetooth. One more question for you guys, could I get more informations (algos,links etc) about messages ID to prevent flooding my own network ?

Comment: **First, the kinds of things you are thinking about are not hex, they are binary**.  In binary computers, hex only exists in an encoded representation such as ASCII - the information is binary as it goes down the wire, and only becomes hex if you write specialized software to translate it or use a hex dumper configured for the appropriate endianness.  Second, you are mistaken in the level of the information involved - an IP packet has binary fields, but this information is more akin to the headers on an email message being transported within a series of such packets, and those are ASCII.

Comment: @Mathieu660 - actually you can probably send something such as ASCII encoded hex even over the custom RF link, if your bandwidth is twice your needs and you can spare maybe 50 bytes of code space at the transmitter.  Of course you can also make it binary (and if bandwidth constrained will have to), but then you either need a link which gives you packet boundaries or to develop your own cannot-occur-in-data framing delimiter condition, and custom software to break apart packets into a visual representation for debugging.

Comment: And like every computer programmer and hardware engineer I've ever met, when we talk about long numbers in binary, we say hex.  Notice in my original post I say a string of bytes.  Not a string of hex characters.  That would be truly pointless.  And he's talking about a mesh network-  a serious one of those would be working at the IP layer or lower.  The address would be directly equivalent to IP address, or even MAC address on the ethernet level.